# React Native useState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, use-state, stack-navigator

When I tried to use useState I get this error:
Component Exception

(0,_reactNative.useState) is not a function.(In'(0,_reactNative.useState)(false)','(0,reactNative.useState)' is undefined)

Source
var children = Component(props, secondArg);

Please help me. I dont understand why I cannot use useState:(

Here is my code:
`

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,View,Text, Modal,useState} from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer,NavigationContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import HomeScreen from './android/screens/HomeScreen/index';
import LoginScreen from './android/screens/Login/index'

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  
  {
    
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
},
{
  initialRouteName:'Login'
}
  
);
const AppContainer= createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default function App ()  {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

    

    return (
      
      <AppContainer/>
      
      
    )
  }
```

Comment: import it from `react`, not `react-native`.

Comment: I love you  bro thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Nicholas, import useState from `react` and not from `react-native`,

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,View,Text, Modal} from 'react-native';
```